# Chrome Issue with floating sandbag elements

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm having issues in Chrome where paragraph text is overlapping floating elements. The floating elements are pushed down to force an image in the lower left-hand corner of a container. I've setup http://jsfiddle.net/VMJGX/ which recreates the issue. The text overlaps the .indenter elements in Chrome but not in Firefox or IE. Is this a Chrome bug or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Chrome Version 21.0.1180.82

Firefox Version 15.0

Comment: Are you just trying to get a way to wrap text around an image?

Comment: Yes, it is to wrap text around an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be that the top of your indenters are getting caught in the middle of lines because of the varying heights compared to the linehieght in the paragraph. I'm guessing FF and Chrome render the heights slightly differently. If you want continue to use the same method you are using, I would recommend **getting rid of the height class styles and instead just use *nbsp;* to fill the indenter divs** so you get height that is consistent with the line height of the paragraph.

[Here's a fiddle with an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/digthedoug/58fkC/)

**UPDATE:**

I updated the fiddle to use spans as the indenters inside the paragraph (instead of divs) and put the width properties back in. Because of the *margin-bottom* on the paragraphs and the *clear* on the indenters, **you need a matching margin-bottom on the intenders so they will stay aligned.**

Comment: I found that I still run into an issue when there is a break between paragraphs. Fiddled here: http://jsfiddle.net/58fkC/1/

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I'll take another look at a different solution.

Comment: I believe that due to the clear you have on the indenting items, you are going to have to match the paragraph's margin on the last indent item. It kinda sucks, but I'm not sure it will work any other way with the margin on the paragraph. I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/digthedoug/58fkC/

Comment: Yeah, it just seems like is should just work easily. I've implemented this as a workaround for the time being. I'll have to keep looking at it.

Comment: I don't see a way around the line-height issue with Chrome and don't think there is another answer out there.